# Can i just define CUDA kernels in .h files?

Tags: cuda

I have difficulties understanding the way i should handle different files in a CUDA program:

I am trying to restructure a CUDA program i have been working on for a while. So far it was more or less a one-file-program. I had 1 .cu file which contained all the CUDA code as well as the main function. I had several header files that were included, but they contained only non-CUDA functions. The program is getting bigger and messier and i want to structure the kernels into different files for readability.

Initially i thought the way to do this is to have .cuh files. I didn't get that to work, so i tried to get my head around [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda), which suggests a .h file and a .cu file. However the program would not build anymore after including other .cu files in it. It would typically either not recognize CUDA keywords such als "__global__" or it would throw errors in external includes, which seemed unrelated.

I noticed however, that it builds when i define the kernel in a .h file. I have the feeling this is not a good idea, but don't know what the problem with it is. 
What bothers me, is that from my understanding the .h files should not even be compiled by nvcc, so how does it still work?
I have great trouble understanding what the best way to go about this is.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and CUDA 5.5

Comment: "Initially i thought the way to do this is to have .cuh files. I didn't get that to work ..." <-- what exactly you mean by that? Thats basically what I am doing within my VS2012 projects with no problem. Are you adding .cuh files directly via VS UI? I mean Add -> New Item -> NVIDIA CUDA <version> -> Code -> CUDA C/C++ Header ?

Comment: yes, that's basically what i did: add a new .cuh, include that in my main file (a .cu) and expect it to work. And it didn't. The same thing with a .h file, and it worked.

Comment: Oh cmon, you just changed the wording from "i didnt get that to work" to "expect it to work and it didnt" :D Seriously, how is anybody supposed to know what was the problem you encountered using your approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules and behavior here aren't really any different conceptually than what is permissible in C or C++ coding.

For a file that is explicitly included in another file via an `#include` directive, the file name, and indeed the file extension - `.cu`, `.h`, `.cuh`. `.hpp` or what have you, really doesn't matter.  That is just a directive to the compiler to pick up that file, and insert it at this point in the source, just as if it had been typed there.

So a statement like I couldn't get `.cuh` to work but I could get `.h` to work really doesn't make sense.  The compiler doesn't care about the filename.  Things like `.cuh` and `.h` are just naming conventions to help us organize large code bases.

Files don't get compiled unless they are in or included in a source module (e.g. `.cu` or `.c` or `.cpp`, etc.)  The compiler doesn't separately compile header files (precompiled headers is another subject, not relevant to this discussion).  It only compiles them if they are included in a source module.

The danger of defining a function in a header file is that if you include the header file in more than one source module, the funcion will be defined (i.e. compiled in) more than one source module.  Usually you don't want this, as it tends to lead to multiple definition errors.

If you intend a header file to be included in one and only one source module, there is no real problem with placing some of your code (i.e. definitions) in that header file.  But the typical usage for header files is *declarations*, not *definitions*.

A `__global__` function for this discussion is really no different than any other C/C++ function.  Putting a kernel definition in a header file runs the risk of multiple definition errors, if you include it in more than one source module.  If you only include it in one source module, it's fine if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. What you write about the way include works makes sense, although it doesn't explain why the same code in a ".cuh" would not build and in a ".h" it does. Probably I made some other mistake or setting in Visual Studio that interferes.